# Facebook comment box social plugin

Tags: facebook

The comment box is live and people can leave comments. The thing is I can't moderate those comments if someone leaves it, it is just there I can't do anything about it.

```
<meta property="fb:moderator" content="278722385507366"/>
```

I added the above but it keeps saying that property is not supported in HTML5 ... is this the only way or there is another way to get to a comment box.

Answer (score -1):

Where did you see the 'fb:moderator' tag listed? shouldn't it be fb:admins?

Comment: To make it more clear `code`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">

 <head> 
 <meta property="fb:admins" content="278722385507366"/>
 <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 <title>Mikhail Photography | Home</title>
`code` I did change it to admins however it is still the same. My website I am working on is www.mikhailphotography.com

Comment: According to the debug tool, 278722385507366 isn't a valid user ID, if it's an app ID the tag to use is fb:app_id (though you can use both) - see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/ for more info

Comment: Igy thank you for being so helpful. I would really appreciate if you could let me know the link to that debug tool that you are using. I think my id is 287748627914749. The problem is it keeps saying that meta property="fb:admins" is not allowed in HTML 5 should I worry about it or not? (I had to look up my id by going to one of my pictures and looking at the url in the browser. Not sure if there is an easier way.)

Comment: Debug tool is at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug - not sure about HTML5 validation but i think there's a namespace declaration you can make to make the fb: prefix recognised

Comment: Hello Igy ... I am really frustrated with this Facebook Comment Box really not sure what else to try. That link does work and everything checks out. However on my website I can only delete my OWN comments and not anybody else. Also where are those comments going once they get posted. They are not on Facebook nor on my website where the heck are they??? How the hell do I get to them to I can remove some.https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://www.mikhailphotography.com/photos/portfolio/Redwoods_National_Park_Orick_CA_HDR.jpg it shows 3 comments but I can only delete one. ???

Comment: There's an open bug at the moment about the admins on like buttons not updating correctly, it could be affecting your comments plugin too: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/325025000856904

Comment: Thanks Igy, this must be it then ... after all I decided to abandon Facebook Comment Box. Thought about it and dont' really see a use for it. Just going to have Like button and G+. Also will store images on amazon S3 server. Thanks for all the help!